# NodeMCU Update TXT File Online

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

New to ESP8266 and NodeMCU.
Seeking to update a text file stored on my website.
Have reviewed http.put and client.print but the results have not achieved the desired deletion of the content and replacing of string.
Constructed a php file to read the url string in hopes of perhaps just having NodeMCU load the url and the php would update the txt but while manually in a browser it works, with http.get it leaves it blank.

```
  HTTPClient http;

  if (lstate == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("L");
    http.begin("http://website.com/flp/flp.php?status=1");
  } else if (rstate == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("R");
    http.begin("http://website.com/flp/flp.php?status=0");
  }

  int httpCode = http.GET();
  http.end();
```

Using Arduino IDE to write and upload shd that matter. Very simply want to update a txt file with a single digit reflected by a series of buttons attached to the NodeMCU. Thx!

Comment: Look at your website's access logs, to see if the requests are getting through at all?  Note that your code as shown is capable of calling http.GET() without ever having called http.begin() (if neither button is pressed), which seems like a potential problem.

Comment: Log shows [18/Jul/2017:22:13:25 -0400] "GET /flp/flp.php?status=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "ESP8266HTTPClient" which shows it got the addy but why did it not load it so that it writes to the txt file?

Comment: The problem would appear to be on the PHP side, then.

Comment: It works in the browser from the address bar. ie http://website.com/flp/flp.php?status=0 /// Here is the flp.php file  <?php
$onoroff = $_GET["state"];
$textfile = "flp.txt";
$fileLocation = "$textfile";
$fh = fopen($fileLocation, 'w   ') or die("Crap!");
$stringToWrite = "$onoroff";
fwrite($fh, $stringToWrite);
fclose($fh); 
?>

Comment: That code is using a query parameter named `state`.  Your NodeMCU code is sending a parameter named `status`.

Comment: Holy crap I am a moron. I thank you for tolerating such a buffoon over sight. Hey, my name has never been more fitting. Damn it. Thanks again!